# Using Kivy's Settings as a Screen

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to create an application with a `Settings` screen (in a `ScreenManager`). How do I place the `Settings` into a `Screen` so I can place the `Screen` into a `ScreenManager` so when the `Screen` is navigated to the `Settings` instance is rendered, then is hidden with it is navigated away from it?

Comment: Did you try anything? How does your code look like now?

Comment: The standard method of displaying the settings appears to be `open_settings()` but after examining the return value (which is boolean) I don't know how to retrieve the widget to have the `Screen` instance store (and display).

In short, I haven't explicitly tried to attach it to the `Screen` because I don't see how to do it (even though the documentation indicates it can be added to a `ScreenManager`).

Comment: So you want an example on how to use screens?

Comment: You want `App.display_settings`, see [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.display_settings).

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/inclement/noGo/blob/master/noGo/main.py#L1067) is an example using a Screen.

Comment: @inclement's [open-source `noGo` Kivy app](https://github.com/inclement/noGo/blob/master/noGo/main.py#L1067) is *mostly* what everyone wants here: a concise (yet practical) real-world example integrating `Settings` **+** `Screen`. **Caveat:** `noGo` is GPL-encumbered, which is non-ideal. Nonetheless, thanks a heap for `noGo`, @inclement!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic example on how to use screenmanager with 2 screens.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import  Label



class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenOne,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.label1 = Label(text="One label on screen 1")
        self.label2 = Label(text="Another label label")

        self.button = Button(text="Go to screen 2")
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)

        self.box.add_widget(self.label1)
        self.box.add_widget(self.label2)

        self.box.add_widget(self.button)

        self.add_widget(self.box)

    def change_screen(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'



class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.label1 = Label(text="One label on screen 2")
        self.label2 = Label(text="Another label label")

        self.button = Button(text="Go to screen 1")
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)

        self.box.add_widget(self.label1)
        self.box.add_widget(self.label2)

        self.box.add_widget(self.button)

        self.add_widget(self.box)

    def change_screen(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'



class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()

        self.sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name = "screen1"))
        self.sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name = "screen2"))


    def build(self):
        return self.sm



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: This only shows how to build an app with screen manager it doesn't show how to set the settings panel in a screen as asked by OP.